# Simple explanation of the differentiation of $\ln(f(x))$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

Could somebody explain why the derivative of $\ln[f(x)]$ = $f'(x)/f(x)$ .

Why is it not simply $1/f(x)$ as is the case for the derivative of $\ln(x)$ being $1/x$?

Comment: Due to the Chain Rule

Comment: Yes, chain rule. Perhaps a counter example will also help convince you: $d/dx(\ln x^n) = n/x \neq 1/x^n$ for all $n \neq 1$

Comment: @GNUSupporter That does make it much more clearer! So since f(x) is a function and not simply x, the chain rule would apply?

Comment: Yes, provided that $f(x) > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

We note first
$$
x = f(f^{-1}(x)) \Rightarrow \\
1 = f'(f^{-1}(x)) (f^{-1})'(x) \Rightarrow \\
(f^{-1})'(x) = 1 / f'(f^{-1}(x))
$$
so using $f(x) = e^x$ we get
$$
(\ln x)' = 1/e^{\ln(x)} = 1/x
$$
For
$$
(\ln(f(x))' = (\ln)'(f(x)) f'(x) = (1/f(x)) f'(x)
$$
we used the chain rule.

Comment: x = fof^-1(x)    =>  x is a  number.

Comment: (lnx)'  is a function .   (lnx)' = 1/x ...a function is a number ?

Comment: $x$ is a function as well, the identiy function. Its derivative regarding $x$ is $1$.

Comment: mvm is almost correct..x is a function. See my " Functions &Systems of Basic Mathematics"

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of $\log(f(x))$ with respect to $x$ is given by the chain rule.  Let $y=f(x)$.

Noting that the derivative of $\log(y)$ with respect to $y$ is $\frac1y$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\log(f(x))&=\left(\left.\frac{d\log(y)}{dx}\right)\right|_{y=f(x)}\\\\
&=\left(\left.\frac{d\log(y)}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\right|_{y=f(x)}\\\\
&=\left.\left(\frac1y \frac{dy}{dx}\right)\right|_{y=f(x)}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{f(x)}\frac{df(x)}{dx}\\\\
&=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can. - Mark

Comment: Shall I delete my answer then?  - Mark

Answer (score 0):

what we wish to find is 
$$\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{\ln f(x+\Delta x)-\ln f(x)}{\Delta x}$$
This can be found easily by using the chain rule (e.g. $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta u}\cdot\frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x}$).

What $1/f(x)$ represents is

$$\lim_{\Delta f(x)\to 0} \frac{\ln (f(x)+\Delta f(x))-\ln f(x)}{\Delta f(x)}$$